# Is it somehow possible to link the view port width to the transform: rotate(degree) value?

Tags: html, css

I would like to do the heading as diagonal as the divider below. The degree of the upper line from the divider depends on the view port width.

So my question is, if it's somehow possible to do a `transform: rotate()` with a `calc(100vw * 1deg)` in it? Unfortunately it doesn't work, because there seems to be a problem with the inappropriate unit.

I know it's quite easy to do this with JavaScript, but is it also possible with CSS only?

[image: Problem]

The code can be found here: https://github.com/openscript/funky-aslant-theme

Comment: no it's not possible but share the code we may find another workaround